# NoMethodError in <main>': undefined methodGiven' for main:Object (NoMethodError)

Tags: cucumber

When I try to run the step_definition,I get the error in ': undefined method Given' for main:Object (NoMethodError)

My Ruby cucumber setup does not recognize the Given,When and Then methods.Should I install any gem to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to run your step definition file directly. You cannot do that.

Instead, you want to run cucumber for your features (rather than the step definitions). When cucumber is run, it will go and collect your step definitions for you (assuming you followed the correct structure).

1. Open a command prompt
2. Go to the folder that contains your `features` directory
3. Type 'cucumber'
4. Press